# How to define a partial object with JSDoc (make all properties optional)

Tags: types, jsdoc

How do I define a type that accepts some or all of an object's properties? I know I can mark each property as optional, but is there a way to make all properties optional?

```js
const defaults = {
    host: 'localhost',
    distDir: 'dist',
    entrypoint: '__app.html',
    app: `build/bundle.js`,
    spaPort: "5000",
    ssrPort: "5005",
    serveSpa: false,
    serveSsr: false,
}

/** 
* @param {defaults} options 
*/
function merge(options = {}){
  const allOptions = {...defaults, ...options)
}
```

The above code shows a warning as `{}` doesn't satisfy `defaults`. Can I define the param `_options` to accept any subset of `defaults`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved with

```js
/** @param {Partial<defaults>} options */
```

Comment: Partial and other "Utility Types": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html